# Ruby on Rails: How to print a string with quotes in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I just want to add `class="home"`:

```
<body <%= ( params[:controller]=='pages' && params[:action]=='home' ? "class=\"home\"" : nil ) %> >
```

When I inspect the source code I see this: `<body class=""home"" style>`

Why the double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a Rails issue!

`"class='home'".html_safe`

I guess Rails escapes all strings by default.

Comment: Rails does this because 99% of the time you're unaware you're making a mistake, and 1% of the time you need to tell Rails "Don't worry, it's cool, render it as-is."